# scrapy startproject error in WIndows XP Home edition

Tags: scrapy

Windows XP, Anaconda. i get the following error and traceback history after performing the "scrapy startproject tutorial" command. for reference, i am mostly following this document's instructions: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

*Command Prompt History*:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda>scrapy startproject tutorial

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda\Scripts\scrapy-scrip
t.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scrapy.cmdline
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sc
rapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sc
rapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sc
rapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sc
rapy\http\request\form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HP_Owner\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\lx
ml\html\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing the DLL for lxml, you can get all the python libs from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Try installing lxml from there.